# Combine multi feature extractors

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning, computer-vision

I would like to know, if you have any idea about how to combine multi feature extractors to get better performance in classification. For example, in Nilsback paper ["Automated flower classification over a large number of classes"](http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/publications/papers/nilsback08.pdf) they have combined 4 different feature extractor. I would like to know how to do that if you have any idea?

P.s. my work is in C++/opencv

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: Please post a link to your cited paper

Comment: here you go,

http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/publications/papers/nilsback08.pdf

Comment: What do you want - improve a detection rate or make your code work faster?

Comment: I want to know, how to combine more than one feature extractor in the same code

Comment: The paper actually does what you want. The authors use a weighted combination of features obtained using four differen feature extractors to classify the images. What is your problem with it?

Comment: My problem in the coding part, I have done implementing hog, SIFT and fast feature detectors, so how to combine them together to get better performance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general if you have multiple feature extractors, each of them giving you a description as a vector, the way to combine them is just concatenating the vectors. However, by doing this you loose information, you could have used, for example, the fact that some feature descriptor is a probability distribution.

In case of SVM, one way how to exploit some further knowledge about your descriptors, is to use a linear combination of separate kernels, where each of these kernels goes with one of your descriptors. Then you can fit the kernels to their descriptors, as well as the weights in the linear combination. This technique is called "Multiple Kernel Learning".

Some pointers which may be useful:

- [a paper on MKL and SVM](http://www.di.ens.fr/~fbach/skm_icml.pdf) by Francis Bach, also cited in the paper you refer to
- [NIPS'09 workshop on MKL](http://mkl.ucsd.edu/workshop) and [NIPS'10 workshop on MKL](http://doc.ml.tu-berlin.de/mkl_workshop/)

Comment: Thank you so much, I have red about it and I found out that I have to use what you said about svm multiple kernel learning (one vs the rest) . I accept your answer(but one question, as the first suggest, what do you think if I will combine SIFT descriptor and HOG descriptor??)

Comment: SIFT+HOG: can work well together if you know what you are doing. There are some comments about this combination in the paper you refer to, so read it once more. Also try to understand what are the common/different aspects SIFT vs. HOG.